# Bubble sort examination

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I solved bubble sort in an exam, but the examiner wasn't satisfied with the solution. Please tell me why my solution is unsatisfactory.

```
function bubbleSort(myArray){
  var temp = undefined,isSwap = false;

  for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
   if(((x+1) <= (myArray.length - 1)) && myArray[x] > myArray[x+1]){
     temp = myArray[x];
     myArray[x] = myArray[x+1];
     myArray[x+1] = temp;
     isSwap = true;           
   }else if(isSwap === true && x === (myArray.length - 1)){
     x = -1;
     isSwap = false;
   }else{
     continue;
   }
 }
 return myArray;
}
```

Just to see the performance I added a print statement i.e. console.log
in the start of the loop like below

```
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
    console.log(myArray);
```

This is what I am able to see for the specific input:

```
console.log(bubbleSort([5,1,6,2,0]));
```

Output:

```
rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$ node sorting.js 
[ 5, 1, 6, 2, 0 ]
[ 1, 5, 6, 2, 0 ]
[ 1, 5, 6, 2, 0 ]
[ 1, 5, 2, 6, 0 ]
[ 1, 5, 2, 0, 6 ]
[ 1, 5, 2, 0, 6 ]
[ 1, 5, 2, 0, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 5, 0, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 0, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 0, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 0, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 0, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 0, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 0, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 0, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 0, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: *"Please tell me why my solution in unsatisfactory"*. You should ask ***your examiner*** why they weren't satisfied.

Comment: Please state in the title of your question only what the purpose of your code is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Zeta said, only your examiner can tell you why he wasn't satisfied.
But here are a couple of suggestions anyway:

- Variable names are important and `myArray` doesn't mean much. You can try `inputArray` for example.
- Changing the index of a for loop is usually not a good idea, because it makes the code a bit more difficult to understand (not by a lot, but why make it harder?).

This is another go at the same algorithm, which I think is more readable:

```
function bubbleSort(inputArray)
{
  var index;
  var done = false;
  var temp;

  while ( !done )
  {
    done = true;
    for(var index = 0; index < inputArray.length; index++)
    {
      if ( inputArray[index] > inputArray[index+1] )
      {
        temp = inputArray[ index ];
        inputArray[ index ] = inputArray[ index+1 ];
        inputArray[ index+1 ] = temp;
        done = false;
      }
    }
  }

  return inputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> function bubbleSort(myArray){
>   var temp = undefined,isSwap = false;
>
>   for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
>    if(((x+1) <= (myArray.length - 1)) && myArray[x] > myArray[x+1]){
>      temp = myArray[x];
>      myArray[x] = myArray[x+1];
>      myArray[x+1] = temp;
>      isSwap = true;           
>    }else if(isSwap === true && x === (myArray.length - 1)){
>      x = -1;
>      isSwap = false;
>    }else{
>      continue;
>    }
>  }
>  return myArray;
> }
> ```

Lets go from top to bottom.

- declaring multiple variables on the same line reduces the readability of your code. Readability is a key aspect in programming. If a reader of your code can't grasp at first glance what your code is doing then you have done something wrong.
- you should declare your variables as near to their usage as possible. This means e.g you should declare the `temp` variable inside the first `if` block.
- you are using 2 times `myArray.length -1` so it would be better to extract this to a variable.
- The swapping of the array elements should be done in a separate method so its intent is more clear and your `bubbleSort()` method will be shorter.
- the `continue` in the `else` part is superflous because the loop wouldn't do anything different than continue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code following some clean up that @Heslacher explained.

```
function bubbleSort(inputArray) {
    var n = inputArray.length;
    var hasSwapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i < n - 1 && inputArray[i] > inputArray[i + 1]) {
            var temp = inputArray[i];
            inputArray[i] = inputArray[i + 1];
            inputArray[i + 1] = temp;
            hasSwapped = true;
        } else if (hasSwapped && i === n - 1) {
            i = -1;
            hasSwapped = false;
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

*Attention for*

1. Spacing
2. Unnecessary code
3. Variable names

   1. Prefer *i* for counters
   2. Avoid *myXyz* for anything
   3. *isSwap* is not exact what you want to inform
4. Complex boolean expressions
5. Avoid parenthesis on boolean expression ===, == have lower precedence than other operators.

[Operators precedence in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).